# Getting Error Ora-1489: Concatenated string is too long when I use LISTAGG

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is the Sql. I am trying to use XMLAGG.

```
SELECT distinct  LEARN_OBS_LCODE                       "KEY", 
       'Results'                              "TEMPLATE", 
       'en-US'                                "LOCALE", 
       'html'                                 OUTPUT_FORMAT, 
       'TTX Checklist Activity Notification' "OUTPUT_NAME", 
       'EMAIL'                                DEL_CHANNEL, 
        LEARN_OBS_EMAIL                    "PARAMETER1",
         --                    "PARAMETER2",
       'ejjc.fa.sender@workflow.mail.us6.oraclecloud.com' "PARAMETER3", 
       '(' || LEARN_OBS_LNAME || ') ' || 'Observation Checklist Pending' 
       || ' - ' 
       || To_char(sysdate, 'MM/DD/YYYY')      "PARAMETER4", 
       'true'                                 "PARAMETER6"
       
       

FROM  (select DISTINCT rtrim(LOCT.internal_location_code) LEARN_OBS_LCODE,
              rtrim(LOC.location_name) LEARN_OBS_LNAME,
            listagg((PEA.EMAIL_ADDRESS || ','|| LOBS.EMAIL1), ',') within group (order by LOCT.internal_location_code) LEARN_OBS_EMAIL
            --XMLAGG(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,PEA.EMAIL_ADDRESS|| ','|| LOBS.EMAIL1 || ',')).extract('//text()') order by LOCT.internal_location_code).getClobaVal() as LEARN_OBS_EMAIL

             FROM fusion.per_all_people_f PAPF 
      INNER JOIN fusion.per_person_names_f PER 
               ON PAPF.person_id = PER.person_id 
                  AND Trunc(sysdate) BETWEEN PER.effective_start_date AND 
                                             PER.effective_end_date 
                  AND PER.name_type = 'GLOBAL'
      LEFT JOIN FUSION.PER_USERS PLU  
               ON PLU.PERSON_ID = PAPF.PERSON_ID  
                   AND Trunc(sysdate) BETWEEN PLU.START_DATE AND NVL(PLU.END_DATE,Trunc(sysdate))
                   AND PLU.ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y'
                   --AND PLU.USERNAME  = FND_GLOBAL.USER_NAME 
      LEFT JOIN FUSION.PER_USER_ROLES PUR     
               ON PUR.USER_ID = PLU.USER_ID 
                   AND Trunc(sysdate) BETWEEN PUR.START_DATE AND NVL(PUR.END_DATE, Trunc(sysdate))
      LEFT JOIN FUSION.PER_ROLES_DN PR_BASE   
               ON PR_BASE.ROLE_ID = PUR.ROLE_ID
      LEFT JOIN FUSION.PER_ROLES_DN_TL PLR    
               ON PLR.ROLE_ID = PR_BASE.ROLE_ID 
                   AND PLR.LANGUAGE = USERENV('LANG')  
                   AND PLR.ROLE_NAME IS NOT NULL       
       INNER JOIN fusion.per_all_assignments_f ASG 
               ON ASG.person_id = PAPF.person_id 
                  AND Trunc(sysdate) BETWEEN ASG.effective_start_date AND 
                                             ASG.effective_end_date 
                  AND ASG.primary_flag = 'Y' 
                  AND ASG.assignment_type IN ( 'E', 'C','N' ) 
                  AND ASG.effective_latest_change = 'Y' 
                  AND ASG.assignment_status_type <> 'INACTIVE' 
       LEFT JOIN per_location_details_f_vl LOC 
              ON ASG.location_id = LOC.location_id 
                 AND Trunc(sysdate) BETWEEN LOC.effective_start_date AND 
                                            LOC.effective_end_date 
       LEFT JOIN per_locations LOCT 
              ON LOC.location_id = LOCT.location_id 
                 
       LEFT JOIN fusion.per_email_addresses PEA 
              ON PEA.person_id = PAPF.person_id 
                 AND Trunc(sysdate) BETWEEN PEA.date_from AND 
                                            Nvl(PEA.date_to, Trunc( 
                                            sysdate)) 
                 AND PEA.email_type = 'W1' 
                 
         inner JOIN LEARN_OBSERVER LOBS
                       ON ASG.LOCATION_ID = LOBS.LOCATION_ID
         WHERE  Trunc(sysdate) BETWEEN PAPF.effective_start_date AND 
                                       PAPF.effective_end_date
                        --and papf.person_number = '38148'                                  

AND UPPER(PR_BASE.ROLE_COMMON_NAME) = 'TTX_LEARNING_OBSERVER_BY_LOCATION_DATA'
--AND UPPER(PLR.ROLE_NAME) = 'TTX LEARNING OBSERVER BY LOCATION'

               
GROUP BY LOCT.internal_location_code , LOC.location_name
```

Comment: When I try to use XMLAGG function, getting not a grouping function error

Comment: this is the piece of code

Comment: listagg((PEA.EMAIL_ADDRESS || ','|| LOBS.EMAIL1), ',') within group (order by LOCT.internal_location_code) LEARN_OBS_EMAIL --XMLAGG(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,PEA.EMAIL_ADDRESS|| ','|| LOBS.EMAIL1 || ',')).extract('//text()') order by LOCT.internal_location_code).getClobaVal() as LEARN_OBS_EMAIL

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE]. The operative words being "minimal" and "reproducible". For minimal: please reduce your code to an example that demonstrates the issue without all the unnecessary joins and without all the extra columns. For reproducible: please include the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements necessary to replicate the issue and then tell us what the expected output should be for that input.